# PHP add array values with same date

Tags: php, arrays

If view is less than one I would like to output to remain as it is but if view > 0 I would like to add all the values that share the same date and output it like:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 09-04-2018
            [value] => 30
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 10-04-2018
            [value] => 32
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 11-04-2018
            [value] => 34
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 12-04-2018
            [value] => 36
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [date] => 13-04-2018
            [value] => 39
        )
)
```

I am using the following code which works for view = 0 but does not add the correct values when view = 1:-

```
$view = 1;

$a = array(
        array('name' => 'Days','date' => '09-04-2018','value' => '10'),
        array('name' => 'Nights','date' => '09-04-2018','value' => '20'),
        array('name' => 'Days','date' => '10-04-2018','value' => '11'),
        array('name' => 'Nights','date' => '10-04-2018','value' => '21'),
        array('name' => 'Days','date' => '11-04-2018','value' => '12'),
        array('name' => 'Nights','date' => '11-04-2018','value' => '22'),
        array('name' => 'Days','date' => '12-04-2018','value' => '13'),
        array('name' => 'Nights','date' => '12-04-2018','value' => '23'),
        array('name' => 'Days','date' => '13-04-2018','value' => '14'),
        array('name' => 'Days','date' => '13-04-2018','value' => '24'),
        array('name' => 'Days','date' => '13-04-2018','value' => '1')
    );

$i = 0;
foreach ($a as $b)
{
    $date = $b['date'];
    $value = $b['value'];

    $key = $i;

    if ($view > 0)
    {
        if ( $key = array_search($date, array_column($c, 'date')) > 0 )
        {
            $value = $c[$key]['value'] + $value;
        }
        else 
        {
            $key = $i;
        }
    }

    $c[$key]['name'] = 'Combined';
    $c[$key]['date'] = $date;
    $c[$key]['value'] = $value;

    $i++;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($c);
echo "</pre>";
```

can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Where does the variable `$c` come from and what does it contain?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson it's the output later on, but doesn't seem to be initialized before..?

Comment: yes it is another array created to output the results

Comment: If you want us to understand your code, you need to show us _all_ relevant code (like where you define `$c`).

Comment: that line `if ( $key = array_search($date, array_column($c, 'date')) > 0 )` seems to me to be the problem. it does make `$key` true or false, right?

Comment: I havent defined $c as such, I thought it did that when I set it as an output array at the end? No it is not true or false it should be the arrray key number if the date is found @jeff I thought that line was wrong, I have tried seperating it but didnt have much luck with that either

Comment: You should make sure you have error reporting turned on (and probably turn on display_errors). `array_column()` takes an array as the first argument. If you pass something that isn't defined, you should get a notice and a warning: https://3v4l.org/3nAdD

Comment: Yeah I should look into that, I shouldnt have missed the unitiiased array, thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use `$key = $i` in the case of `$view > 0`, but, `$i` could be greater than the current size of `$c`. Then, the comparison with the value of `array_keys` must be a strict comparison the check if the key if different or greater that 0, or false (not found). finally, you need to create an empty array `$c` to start to avoid a warning in `array_column`.

```
$view = 1;
$a = array(
        array('name' => 'Days','date' => '09-04-2018','value' => '10'),
        array('name' => 'Nights','date' => '09-04-2018','value' => '20'),
        array('name' => 'Days','date' => '10-04-2018','value' => '11'),
        array('name' => 'Nights','date' => '10-04-2018','value' => '21'),
        array('name' => 'Days','date' => '11-04-2018','value' => '12'),
        array('name' => 'Nights','date' => '11-04-2018','value' => '22'),
        array('name' => 'Days','date' => '12-04-2018','value' => '13'),
        array('name' => 'Nights','date' => '12-04-2018','value' => '23'),
        array('name' => 'Days','date' => '13-04-2018','value' => '14'),
        array('name' => 'Days','date' => '13-04-2018','value' => '24'),
        array('name' => 'Days','date' => '13-04-2018','value' => '1')
    );

$c =[];
foreach ($a as $i => $b)
{
    $date = $b['date'];
    $value = $b['value'];

    $key = $i;

    if ($view > 0)
    {
        $key = array_search($date, array_column($c, 'date'));
        if ($key !== false)
        {
            $value = $c[$key]['value'] + $value;
        }
        else
        {
            $key = count($c); // Create a new index here instead of $i
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $key = $i;
    }

    $c[$key]['name'] = 'Combined';
    $c[$key]['date'] = $date;
    $c[$key]['value'] = $value;
}

print_r($c);
```

outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Combined
            [date] => 09-04-2018
            [value] => 30
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Combined
            [date] => 10-04-2018
            [value] => 32
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Combined
            [date] => 11-04-2018
            [value] => 34
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Combined
            [date] => 12-04-2018
            [value] => 36
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Combined
            [date] => 13-04-2018
            [value] => 39
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, solved my problem and explained your answer.